# What does "tiny baby" mean here?

Tags: word-meaning

> Two **tiny baby** dolls of unidentified gender, made of hard, matte plastic, and wrapped in blankets of the same kind of plastic.

Does the *tiny baby* mean "extremely small newborn"?

Comment: Please ask one question per question.  I've removed the second question; please feel free to repost it separately.

Answer (score 1):

The logical pattern is *tiny (baby dolls)*.

It's two dolls shaped like babies (as opposed to toddler or adult (-> Barbie)), that are very small.

So small dolls, not necessarily depicting very young/newborn babies.

Answer (score 1):

*tiny* refers to the size of the *baby dolls*, not to the size of the actual *baby*. The dolls themselves are simply small in size.